# Get audio floats from AudioQueueBufferRef output queue callback

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-audio

I been stuck for days trying to get the correct audio floats from a simple **mp3** audio queue output **AudioQueueBufferRef** using .mAudioData

```
let callback : @convention(c) (_ userData : UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
    _ queue : AudioQueueRef,
    _ bufferToFill : AudioQueueBufferRef) -> Void =
    { (userData, queue, bufferToFill) in
        guard let myInfo = userData?.assumingMemoryBound(to: myInfo.self) else {return}

        Utility.check(AudioFileReadPacketData(myInfo.pointee.playbackFile! ,              // AudioFileID
            false,                                     // use cache?
            &numBytes,                                 // initially - buffer capacity, after - bytes actually read
            myInfo.pointee.packetDescs,                // pointer to an array of PacketDescriptors
            myInfo.pointee.packetPosition,             // index of first packet to be read
            &nPackets,                                 // number of packets
            bufferToFill.pointee.mAudioData),          // output buffer
            operation: "AudioFileReadPacketData failed")

      let size = Int((bufferToFill.pointee.mAudioDataBytesCapacity) / 2 )
      let array = Array(UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: bufferToFill.pointee.mAudioData.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int16.self), count: size))
      print(array[0...5],"int16")

      //to floats
      let numSamples = array.count / MemoryLayout<Int16>.size //2
      var factor = Float(Int16.max)

      var floatsArr: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: numSamples)
      var scaledFloats: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: numSamples)
      print(array[0...20],scaledFloats.count,"int16")

      vDSP_vflt16(array, 1, &floatsArr, 1, vDSP_Length(numSamples))
      print(array[0...20],scaledFloats.count,"floats")

      vDSP_vsdiv(&floatsArr, 1, &factor, &scaledFloats, 1, vDSP_Length(numSamples))//scaling
      print(scaledFloats[0...20],scaledFloats.count, "scaledfloats \n")
```

}

I'm getting the wrong floats, but I'm able to playback successfully. I want to draw a waveform from **AudioQueueBufferRef**

Thank you!
If you want to try it
https://github.com/masaldana2/getmAudioData

Comment: It seems like you forgot to push some commits in this repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
let numSamples = array.count / MemoryLayout<Int16>.size //2
```

By:

```
let numSamples = array.count
```

I believe that your float buffers are half the expected size, otherwise.

Here is a modified, standalone version of a subset of your code, that I used for testing:

```
import Foundation
import Accelerate

let size = 7
var data : [Int16] = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -Int16.max, Int16.max ]

let array = Array(UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: &data, count: size))

var floatsArr:    [Float] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: array.count)
var scaledFloats: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: array.count)

vDSP_vflt16(array, 1, &floatsArr, 1, vDSP_Length(array.count))

var factor = Float(Int16.max)
vDSP_vsdiv(floatsArr, 1, &factor, &scaledFloats, 1, vDSP_Length(array.count))

print(       array[0 ...        array.count - 1],        array.count, "int16")
print(   floatsArr[0 ...    floatsArr.count - 1],    floatsArr.count, "float")
print(scaledFloats[0 ... scaledFloats.count - 1], scaledFloats.count, "scaled")
```

And its output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -32767, 32767] 7 int16
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, -32767.0, 32767.0] 7 float
[0.0, 3.05185094e-05, 6.10370189e-05, 9.15555283e-05, 0.000122074038, -1.0, 1.0] 7 scaled
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried what you said and I get noise. Maybe I'm getting the wrong data from mAudioData? here's the file if you want to look at it https://github.com/masaldana2/getmAudioData

Comment: @masaldana2 Are you sure all the code is in there? I only see an empty app shell there.

Comment: I think you are currently converting raw undecoded MP3 frames into float buffers... Playback works because the output queue actually can play them directly.

Comment: I see, so I guess I need to encode it first right ? :) before converting to floats. I just want to draw a waveform

Comment: You meant decode? Assuming yes: I wouldn't recommend that. You'd end up decoding your MP3 frames twice on the device. It's highly inefficient. A far better solution is to leverage audio queue taps, so you can run the float conversion in sync with the audio queue. I'm looking into that right now. It's a bunch of extra code that calls into mostly undocumented APIs...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168686/discussion-between-nicolas-tisserand-and-masaldana2).